# SaveFileDialog existing file

Tags: c#, xml, savefiledialog

I am using the savefiledialog in C# and I am allowing the user to save an xml node to a file however if the user chooses to create a new file and save the node in it, it works but when the user chooses to save to an existing file then it is overwritten. what I need is that it kind of loads the file and I can append the node in it, Thanks

```
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog sfd = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.FileName = "untitled"; // Default file name
        sfd.DefaultExt = ".xml"; // Default file extension
        sfd.Filter = "Xml documents (.xml)|*.xml";
        Nullable<bool> result = sfd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName) != ".xml")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can only choose files with .xml extensions");
                return;
            }
            this.save_xml_file(sfd.FileName);
        }
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no");
        doc.AppendChild(docNode);
        XmlNode fubiRec = Doc.CreateElement("FubiRecognizers");
        XmlAttribute conf = Doc.CreateAttribute("globalMinConfidence");
        conf.Value = "0.51";
        fubiRec.Attributes.Append(conf);
        doc.AppendChild(fubiRec);
        XmlAttribute gestureAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
        gestureAttribute.Value = gestureName;
        gestureNode.Attributes.Append(gestureAttribute);
        fubiRec.AppendChild(gestureNode);
```

Comment: The appending or overwriting operation is determined by the way you write to the file, not how you choose it. Provide the code that you're using to write to the file and we can help.

Comment: I have posted the code if you could help me

Comment: You have not posted the code that you're using to write to the file. You've posted a call to a function (`save_xml_file()`) that writes to the file which we can't see. Once again, please post the code you're using to write to the file.

Comment: ohh :D my bad here it comes

Comment: the part after the } is the save_xml_file

Comment: @user3237272 I still don't see the part where you save the file.

Comment: "the part after the } is the save_xml_file" - No, it isn't. The `save_xml_file` is a method of the form class (that you reference with `this`), and has a declaration, an opening body, variable declarations, and is clearly distinct and readable. If you want help here, cooperate and post **your actual code** and make it readable. If you don't want to take the time to clearly state your question and provide details, you're wasting both our time and yours here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use FileStream and StreamWriter then you need to specify your type of Stream first.

`FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);`

FileMode.Append will create file if it doesn't exist,and append the one that exists.

Then use it in StreamWriter

`StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileSTream, Encoding.Default);`

If you don't use this kind of stream or writer, there is always something similar available.